# Is there a way to list all classes in a project in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

As title, does IntelliJ provide an overview of all classes in a project? (for Java). I want to review the design of my project by listing the classes and the hierarchy between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try `Analyze | Analyze Dependency Matrix...`. The [Dependency Matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/dsm-analysis.html) shows all classes and dependencies between them.

Comment: Is this an Ultimate only feature ? I don't see that in my community edition.

Comment: So the Jetbrains help page said that I have to install DSM Analysis plugin, but I cannot find this plugin in their repository... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, this is an [Ultimate only feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).